# Registering all view controllers for NSNotifications

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a custom graphic that is to be displayed to a user when an event occurs. The graphic needs to be displayed on whichever viewController is currently being displayed to the user.

The way i have programmed it so far is by adding to ALL viewcontrtollers:
1) the .h file for the custom graphic class
2) an observer for the NSNotification event that is raised
3) the method which actually draws the graphic.

This doesnt feel like a very efficient way of doing things and i was wondering if anyone has a better way of doing things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it sounds like you've done it in a fairly sane way. The only other way I can think is to just add the graphic to the window which would then overlay on the current view controller and you'd only need to have one object listening for the notification. You could use the app delegate for instance. But then you would have to worry about rotation of the screen yourself when adding the graphic over the top.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is correct .. The only thing you can improve is to mauve the drawing graphics part to the custom graphic class.. (if you are not already doing so...

just Make a `UIViewController` variable as a `member variable` to the `graphics class`..and then set it up to the current view displaying..after you receive the `notifications`..and the class will itself draw the code based on the `ViewController` you set it up to

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't feel efficient is that you're duplicating a lot of code. That's more work at the outset, and it creates a maintenance headache. You should be taking advantage of the inheritance that's built into object oriented languages, including Objective-C.

If you want all your view controllers to share some behavior, then implement that behavior in a common superclass. Derive all your other view controllers from that superclass, and they'll all automatically get the desired behavior. Your superclass's initializer can take care of registering the view controller for the notification(s) that you care about, and `-dealloc` can unregister it. This way, you don't have to clutter up each view controller with the same repeated code, and if you want to change the code you only have to do it in one place.